# Mautic tracking saving only ip address not location in database

Tags: tracking, mautic

We are hosting Mautic on GCP.

According to mautic documentation we should add below code to track the details of the person visiting the page.

```
<script>
    (function(w,d,t,u,n,a,m){w['MauticTrackingObject']=n;
        w[n]=w[n]||function(){(w[n].q=w[n].q||[]).push(arguments)},a=d.createElement(t),
        m=d.getElementsByTagName(t)[0];a.async=1;a.src=u;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
    })(window,document,'script','http(s)://yourmautic.com/mtc.js','mt');

    mt('send', 'pageview');
</script>
```

We have set configuration correctly even after that it just saving the ip addresses in database not the location (country, state city) and it also not providing correct browser(saving all browser names) and device(not saving it) fingerprint.

Answer (score 0):

Location data is handled by the set up of the MaxMind database or another service.

Make sure that your MaxMind iplookup cron service is appropriately set up and you have the appropriate API credentials for that service or another service (e.g. Clearbit).

https://docs.mautic.org/en/setup/cron-jobs#update-maxmind-geolite2-ip-database